# Why the for loop is not adding numbers for the code?

Tags: javascript, animate.css

I have tried to increase the delay time for a class. But it seems the **adding time for different items doesn't work**. I have console logged `delay` and it shows me 0. What's wrong with my for loop? Why does it not add time or numbers!
And I getting the error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined". But I have defined it in my code: see.

```js
//service list add class
let serviceSection = document.querySelector(".service_section");
let serviceList = document.querySelectorAll(".service-list li");

serviceSection.addEventListener("mouseenter", addAnimation);
function addAnimation() {
  serviceList.forEach((currentItem) => {
    currentItem.classList.add("animate__animated", "animate__fadeInLeft");
  });
  addDelay();
}

//service list animation delay

function addDelay() {
  let time = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < serviceList.length; i++) {
    let delayInTime = time + i;
    let currentElement = serviceList[i];
    console.log(currentElement);
    serviceList[i].style.setProperty("--animate-delay", delayInTime + "s");
  }
  serviceList.style.setProperty("--animate-duration", "1s");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="service_section">
<ul class="service-list">
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: time is 0. and it stays zero...

Comment: forgot to add div section while posting the question. but now why it doesn't add time to every elements?

Comment: Please share more details - your code does not contain any variable called `delay` that should be logged

Answer (score 0):

We understand you are new :). But please do a better job of asking your question. Then you'll get a better answer. There are many talented engineers here.

**EDIT**

**---------------------------------------------------------------**

Thanks for specifying animate.css. It helped alot :) Is this what you were looking for? I think you're making it a little more complicated than it needs to be. We just add a class for each one and give it a 1 second delay.

```js
//service list add class
let serviceSection = document.querySelector(".service_section");
let serviceList = document.querySelectorAll(".service-list li");

serviceSection.addEventListener("mouseenter", addAnimation, {once: true});
function addAnimation() {
  serviceList.forEach((currentItem, idx) => {
    let animateTime = `animate__delay-${idx}s`;
    currentItem.classList.add("animate__animated", "animate__fadeInLeft", animateTime);
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="service_section">
<ul class="service-list">
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
      <li>fjfdkkdkauejfdk dsskkfks </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Couple things to note, notice the use of `{once: true}`. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). The other thing is notice `forEach` has its own index we can use. No need to use an extra for loop.

Comment: yeah ... i am new to stackoverflow and i using animated.css here. but I don't know what's wrong with my code. and couldn't find out the differences between yours and mine. i used for loop to increase the delay.. but why it doesn't peek that particular each element and the specific delay time? I noticed that I am getting same delay for each element. Why it is? Can you explain it briefly?

Comment: I have edited the code.. can you plz look at it again.

Comment: @MoshiurRahmanRony thanks for the update! I have also editted my answer

Comment: For the same delay issue, it's because you're adding `animate__delay` after `animate__animated` and `animate__fadeInLeft`. Unfortunately, animate.css isn't that good where you can add delays at the end. You need to add them at the start along with the other classes.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I've used a different name as my variable but this is a snippet from a code I did ( I removed some stuff that wouldn't make sense since the snippet doesn't include everything) I made sure to show the variable declarations, the event listener and what the input equals in normal terms for imputing a integer value:

```
var timer;
var question;
var loader;
var modeSwitch;
var NUM_QUESTIONS;
var TIMEOUT = 10000;

function initApp(){
    if(instructor()){
    loader = document.querySelector("#loader")
    loader.id="";
    timer=setTimeout(load, 3500);
    answer.addEventListener("onsubmit", validateAnswer, false);
    }else{
        document.write();
```

For this code the 3500 indicates the time out: which equals 3.5 seconds

Comment: actually that answer is not related to my question or I don't get it.. can you explain it briefly and give the point plz.

Comment: Your trying to add a delay, my timeout code is similar and can be used as reference

Comment: yeah, i got it now.. and used 
i*1000;

Comment: That code looks completely different. If you want to help the OP properly, please do not irritate him. Rather take his code, fix it, and explain **how** you fixed it - this helps other to learn from your code